# Only touchscreen on boot

Tags: 13.10, keyboard, mouse, touchscreen, trackpoint

Sometimes when I boot up my Lenovo ThinkPad twist, only the touchscreen works.  The keyboard will work until I log in, but then both the keyboard and touchpad (and trackpoint) stop working.  Only the touchscreen in recognized.

Edit:  After I restart Ubuntu, all input devices work, but if I boot from a shutdown, they don't.

I am currently running Ubuntu 13.10 x64.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Does those work in another user, e.g. Guest Session?

Comment: I just tried it, and they do not work in other users such as the Guest Session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so as Mr. DNA said, It was BIOS related.  Here is how I ended up fixing it:

I downloaded BIOS version **1.52**  Make sure you are downloading that version.
Download it from http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?&DocID=DS032118 it will be on the bottom of the page, so scroll down.

Burn the iso to a CD, a USB will not work, it has to be a CD.

After you burn it to the CD, reboot your computer, and boot into the CD.

Select option 2 when you get the menu. (I forget what it was called)

Once it is done, press enter, and wait until you get the menu again.  Once you get the menu again, remove the disk, and boot as normal.

Your Thinkpad should now work flawlessly.  Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Do some searching.  This is a common problem for any flavor of linux on the twist.  Some have claimed that it is bios related, but there are currently no reported fixes for this problem.

Comment: I have done a lot (a lot lot lot lot) of searching, and no luck.  Thanks anyway though.  If I don't get any other answers soon I'll mark this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

as a simple workaround just connect an external mouse via USB on boot and touchpad, keyboard, etc. will work without a reboot.